# Algorithm for culling pixels in a graphical data view?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, drawing, widget

I'm writing a wxpython widget which shows the state of several objects over time (x cycles). Right now I have it working with 1 pixel/cycle and zooming in and back out to 1:1; but I would like to allow zooming out. I wanted to see if there are any go-to algorithms for thowing away/combining data before I started rolling my own using only my own feeble heuristics. Is there any such algo, or should I just start coding my own solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends a lot on what type of images you're resizing. See [The myth of infinite detail: Bilinear vs. Bicubic](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/the-myth-of-infinite-detail-bilinear-vs-bicubic.html) and [Better Image Resizing](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/07/better-image-resizing.html) by our very own Jeff! There you can compare results of naive nearest neighbor, [bilinear filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_filtering), [bicubic filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_filtering), [bicubic sharper](http://www.photoshopsupport.com/tutorials/jennifer/bicubic.html) and [genuine fractals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genuine_Fractals).

Jeff's conclusion:

> Reducing images is a completely safe
>   and rational operation. You're simply
>   reducing precision and resolution by
>   discarding information. Make the image
>   as small as you want, and you have
>   complete fidelity-- within the bounds
>   of the number of pixels you've
>   a> llowed. You'll get good results no
>   matter which algorithm you pick.
>   (Well, unless you pick the nave Pixel
>   Resize or Nearest Neighbor
>   algorithms.)
>
> Enlarging images is risky. Beyond a
>   certain point, enlarging images is a
>   fool's errand; you can't magically
>   s> ynthesize an infinite number of new
>   pixels out of thin air. And
>   interpolated pixels are never as good
>   as real pixels. That's why it's more
>   than a little artificial to upsize the
>   512x512 Lena image by 500%. It'd be
>   smarter to find a higher resolution
>   scan or picture of whatever you need*
>   than it would be to upsize it in
>   software.
>
> But when you can't avoid enlarging an
>   image, that's when it pays to know the
>   tradeoffs between bicubic, bilinear,
>   and more advanced resizing algorithms.
>   At least arm yourself with enough
>   knowledge to pick the best of the bad
>   options you have.

Comment: The image is basically pixel-art, boxes of primary colors building lines across the screen, 1 per object. 2xSaI looked interesting, but google isn't helping to find a source example :P Interesting links though :)